# How to use a variable to alter a constraint of a table in PL SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to get the name of a constraint and then alter a table to remove the constraint. The constraint has not been named so I guess I have no other option. Here is what I tried:

```
DECLARE
   the_variable VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
   SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME INTO the_variable
FROM all_constraints
WHERE table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
AND SEARCH_CONDITION_VC = 'format IN (''CSV'', ''PDF'')';
END;
```

The query above seems to work fine, but when I try to alter the table in this way:

```
ALTER TABLE SOME_TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT the_variable;
```

I get this error:

```
SQL Error [6550] [65000]: ORA-06550: line 14, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ALTER"
```

Comment: Looks like the issue is how to use the variable, not how to populate it.

Comment: should I rename the question to "how to use a variable?"

Comment: I would say it's more about using a variable in an ALTER TABLE statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't perform DDL like that; has to be *dynamic SQL*. Here's an example - you need what's written in line #9:

```
SQL> create table my_table (id number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> declare
  2    the_variable varchar2(30);
  3  begin
  4    select constraint_name
  5      into the_variable
  6      from all_constraints
  7      where table_name = 'MY_TABLE';
  8
  9    execute immediate 'alter table my_table drop constraint ' || the_variable;
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select count(*) from all_constraints where table_name = 'MY_TABLE';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL>
```